# Setting up one app for two different teams

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, enterprise

I'm very uncomfortable with all that part of the appstore release, so i'll try and explain everything as clearly as possible.

I work with two developer accounts, one is Enterprise , and the other is for the appstore. I've read that the Entreprise can't publish on the app store so we simply paid for one.

We developped the app on the Control account for a while now, and I don't really know how i can "transfer" my app properly.

I'm using different API's that requires keys (like Crashlytics or Parse), also push notifications that requires Certificates, obviously, and all that part is very dark to me. It's working fine right now, and I have a feeling that there should be a simple way to just "switch" accounts.

The problem is : I don't know what I have to set up on my Store account to transfer the app. I'm guessing new  certificates, but then I have to replace the ones on Parse ? Or just change the "team" scrolldown menu?

I have no idea what I should do form here.

I have a working app on a Entreprise account and I don't know the steps to make it work (and uploadable for review) on a regular developer account.

Thank you guys for your time, it is VERY much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A few things here. First of all you **cannot** deploy an app out of one account that has an identical bundle identifier to that in another account. What you're going to have to do is the following assuming you're using your Enterprise app as the baseline:

- create a new bundle identifier in your Company (App Store) account. I would suggest making it similar to the bundle Id from the Enterprise account. ie: com.mycompany.fooEnterprise and com.mycompany.fooAppStore
- likewise create a new provisioning profile for the new bundle identifier.
- import your provisioning profile into Xcode.
- in XCode change your target info bundle identifier to that which you setup in the Company account.
- in the general tab change your team information (assuming XCode 6) to that of the company account
- under your build settings toggle your signing profiles and provisioning profiles to the company account.

Off the top of my head that is all you should have to do in order to successfully compile the app under the secondary account. I consistently deal with 3rd party developers who give me builds where I have to do the opposite (change from Company portal to Enterprise portal).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

- AppStore developer account:

  1. Create an appId with the exact bundle identifier that you are using in your app, not with a wild card (*) as you probably have it in the Enterprise account. Don't forget to check the "Push notifications" App Sevice.
  2. Create a Distribution certificate (AppStore)
  3. Create distribution provisioning profile where you will link the appId and the certificate.
  4. Create push notification certificate: Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production). You will upload this certificate to Parse.
- You don't need to update the keys from Parse since it's the same application.

I hope this helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an answer to a post that is from a few years ago, however, I was looking for setup one Xcode project so it can build on 2 different accounts, the Enterprise account, and the regular AppStore account.

The steps here do get you to where you want to be, but I was looking for a separate target with a different team, bundle id, and provisioning in the same project.  Then easily switch back and forth between the two.  So here is how to do that....

1. Go to the `Project > Targets`, right click on your existing target and select `Duplicate`.  This will make a duplicate target that you can modify but still uses the original code, and Info.plist.  Make sure on your Info.plist under `Bundle Identifier` it says this `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.  This tells it to look elsewhere to get the bundle id, and i believe that elsewhere is under the `Target > General > Identity > Bundle Identifier`.
2. Change the name of the Duplicate target to something else.
3. Fill in the duplicate target with the different Team, bundle id, and provisioning profiles.
4. It also creates a duplicate Scheme for you so you can switch which one to build against on the top menu bar.  Go to the top menu `Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes and select the`Scheme Copy`.  Hit Return and re-name it.

Thats it.  now you should be able to build the same app under 2 different teams.

Comment: `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` is actually based off Build Settings >> Packaging - 'PRODUCT BUNDLE IDENTIFIER'. That's where you can have _Multiple values_ ie have a different value per configuration. If you have different values then all you can see in `Target > General > Identity > Bundle Identifier` is `<Multiple values>`